# Unanswered Question Share Banner Bug

Tags: bug, unanswered-questions, share-this

In unanswered questions across the StackExchange network, there is an ability to share the question via numerous social media outlets. The banner that says this is missing a few things. Here is a picture:
[image: bug]
Obviously, it is missing about **3** ways to share the question. At least we can email. I do remember it being there in full some time ago. I just now noticed it on [History](https://history.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=noanswers), [LEGO® Answers](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=noanswers) and [Biblical Hermeneutics](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=noanswers). I was going to post this in History but decided to check other sites to see if they have the issue too. When I found out they did, I came here to report it.

Comment: Are you using any sort of ad blocker? Because I see those links just fine.

Comment: That explains it. Apparently my adblocker blocked them.

Comment: I added `@@||stackexchange.com/$document` and that fixed the issue